# Method [header] does not exist on view - Laravel 5

Tags: php, model-view-controller, laravel-5

I have created a middleware to restrict the page going back inside the dashboard as follows:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class ValidateBackButton {

/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next)            
    {            
            $response = $next($request);

            $response->header('Cache-Control','nocache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate')
            ->header('Pragma','no-cache') 
            ->header('Expires','Sat, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT');

            return $response;
    }
}
```

I have registered the middleware in app/http/kernel.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => 'App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate',
    'auth.basic' => 'Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth',
    'guest' => 'App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated',
    'validateback' => 'App\Http\Middleware\ValidateBackButton',
];
```

I am using the middleware in my controller:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
    $this->middleware('validateback');
}
```

Everything seems fine, however, i get the following error message:

> BadMethodCallException in View.php line 387:
>
> > Method [header] does not exist on view.

Kindly help me out!

**UPDATE**

I think there should not be any problem with the view, so I've the layout file below. The code for view is too long to put it here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 8]> <html lang="en" class="ie8 no-js"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]> <html lang="en" class="ie9 no-js"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>SB Admin v2.0 in Laravel 5</title>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport"/>
<meta content="" name="description"/>
<meta content="" name="author"/>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset("assets/stylesheets/styles.css") }}" />
</head>
<body>
@yield('body')
<script src="{{ asset("assets/scripts/frontend.js") }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following changes solved my problem:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;

class ValidateBackButton { 

/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next)            
    {            
            //$response = $next($request);

            $response = $next($request);

            $response = $response instanceof RedirectResponse ? $response : response($response);

            return $response->header('Cache-Control','nocache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate')
                            ->header('Pragma','no-cache') //HTTP 1.0
                            ->header('Expires','Sat, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT'); // // Date in the past

            return $response;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by chaining `header` to `$next`:

```
return $next($request)->header('Cache-Control','nocache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate')
            ->header('Pragma','no-cache') 
            ->header('Expires','Sat, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT');
```

If this doesn't help, make sure you're not using `header` elsewhere. From the error message, it appears that you're also using `header` with `view()`. (Might help if you also post your view code).

Comment: Post the code for your view, as error could be coming from there. Specifically, how the controller is rendering the view.

Comment: I've updated with the layout file. View is normal html file under the body section of the layout.

Comment: Thanks. Can you also include how you call the view in the controller, e.g. ```return view('home');```

Comment: return view('home');   as you expected